# JSF - Create a chain of value with EL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I would like to know if its possible, by using JSF, to make somethings like this :

```
<ui:include src="#{bean.value/bean.value}.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="#{bean.value/'default'/bean.value}.xhtml" />
```

In other words, create a chain of EL value (in this example it make sense because i use `ui:include`)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
<ui:include src="#{bean.value}/default/#{bean.value}.xhtml" />
```

Comment: Works. But this doesnt work `<ui:include src="#{bean.value}/#{bean.value}.xhtml" />`

Comment: @markzz try `<ui:include src="#{bean.value}//#{bean.value}.xhtml" />`

Comment: @markzz Try `<ui:include src="${bean.value}/${bean.value}.xhtml" />` :)

Comment: Oh no, was my fault : `<ui:include src="/#{selector.page}/#{selector.page}.xhtml" />` WORKS :) (i forgot the `/` at the start of my include). thanks man